# Install Linux side by side on an encrypted disk running Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, disk-encryption

I have a workplace issued laptop that has Windows 10 installed and BitLocker encyrption enabled. So when I power on the machine, the first thing that happens (after the vendor logo) is BitLocker key prompt, after which Windows starts loading.

Is it even possible to install Linux (Ubuntu or Elementary OS) for dual boot on such a set up? If it is, what is the most minimally invasive method? I am OK with having Windows loader as the primary loader etc. I know running in VirtualBox is an option, but that is too slow and I would prefer native feel.

Comment: You mentioned that it has installed Windows 10, Have you tried [enabling bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36465000/8179876) which will give you a Linux-terminal. (I know that's not exactly what you want, but it's pretty close...) `Note: this requires access to control panel`

Comment: Indeed. I have WSL enabled and I use it. However, I was hoping to get a more complete Linux experience.

Comment: Afraid to try anything! Primarily because of encryption. I have a hunch that i should not mess with bitlocker but not sure how.

Comment: If I were you, I just wouldn't push my luck and just use Linux through a VM. If your boss finds out that you messed with a computer's software he could fire you...

Comment: Useful advice :) However, theoretically, if my life depended on it, is this possible? And if so, how?